# Component based design for angular2.x single page application

Tags: angular, html-table, single-page-application

i am in the process of creating an SPA which displays huge amount of data to the user (mostly) in tabular form. The application essentially has a table structure - with a header with multiple columns and then rows of data - which in some instances is nested. This means that the "parent" row could be expanded to display a "child" row with relevant information  but for all intent and purposes the "child" row is just a "parent" row with a different background color.

Please see the image below 
[image]

the plan is to

1 -  create a component "comp 1" that is re-used across the header row to render every column (since each header column is just a label with a text and a sort asc/desc feature). even in other tables - the headers are pretty much constant and with exact same functionality. Although this offers re-usability - it does have a downside - if my table has 10 columns in the header row - i end up rendering the component 10 times (potential performance degradation).

2 - create a component "comp 2"  this is essentially a entire table row with N columns (configurable) - with a unique style -  and each column with a distinct feature.

3 - re-use "comp 2" with  a overridden style (based on a condition) to render a nested row which essentially is the same as "base" comp 2 but with a different visual style.

4. re-use these components to dynamically create tables (of X rows and Y cols) for all other tabular views.

The potential downside i see is the sheer amount of components i will have to load to render a table, and the potential performance bottleneck i will have to deal with.

For each table i will have - Comp 1 * number of columns (average cols = 15) 
and
Comp 2 * number of rows (average rows = 1500)

Please could anyone advise if this is an acceptable approach and if they have used any alternative approaches to render such visual style.

thanks in advance

Comment: this is opinion based...

Comment: thanks - i agree. would you have any feedback on the feasibility of the design itself and if it is advisable to deal with such large number of components load-unload cycle in angular?